# Construct a 2x2 matrix with real eigenvalues that is not diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I've been banging my head against the table with this one for a while. I know that for it not to be diagonalizable that the columns can't be linearly independent but can't quite seem to come up with one.

Comment: You might want to consider a $2\times 2$ Jordan block.

Comment: What you think you know might not be correct.

Comment: For it not to be diagonalizable all you need is to have an eigenvalue with multiplicity greater than the dimension of the eigenspace. (i.e not enough eigenvectors). This is not related to independence

Comment: Also complex matrices can always be put on a form with either 1s or 0s off the main diagonal and eigenvalues on the diagonal. For real matrices you can be sure to not have to have more than at most blocks of size 2x2 along the diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** A matrix $A$ with geometric multiplicity equal to its algebraic multiplicity is diagonalizable, so any nondiagonalizable $2 \times 2$ matrix must have a single eigenvalue, say, $\lambda$ of algebraic multiplicity $2$ but geometric multiplicity $1$.

**Additional hint** If some invertible matrix $P$ diagonalized $A - \lambda I$, it would diagonalize $A$, a contradiction. Thus, if $A$ is an example, so is $A - \lambda I$, which has eigenvalue $0$ of algebraic multiplicity $2$, and thus we may as well restrict our search to the case $\lambda = 0$.

> Since $A$ satisfies its own characteristic polynomial, $A^2 = 0$, but we cannot have $A = 0$, because $0$ is diagonalizable. Thus, there is a vector ${\bf v} \in \Bbb R^2$ such that $A {\bf v} \neq 0$, so $B = (A {\bf v}, {\bf v})$ is a basis of $\Bbb R^2$. With respect to $B$, the transformation matrix is $$J = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0} .$$ (This is the $2 \times 2$ Jordan block of eigenvalue $0$.) On the other hand, the sole eigenspace of $J$ is spanned by $\pmatrix{1\\0}$, so $J$ and thus $A$ has geometric multiplicity $1$. It follows from our construction that up to similarity and addition of multiples of $I$ this example is unique.